# Running structured text files in Raspberry pi 3

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi3, structured-text

I have my raspberry pi3 and I did a small basic code in a text editor in structured text language. I don't know how to run the code in the terminal. I'm running OPEN PLC in raspberry pi. So there should be some way to run the structured text language code within the terminal.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

I have saved the file in .st extention which seems to be the extension for the structured text file. When I type the filename.st in a terminal, it says command cannot be executed.

The error message when I try to run the code, it says command cannot be executed. I would like to know how to compile and run the file ( in .st Extention) in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

None of the controllers ever run ST code directly. Before it gets to the plc it is compiled at least to С or even Machine code. So you cannot run your ST file directly. The only ways are.

1. You can use logi.CAD3. There is instruction on [how to install](https://help.logicals.com/display/LC3UserDocuEN/Installing+and+starting+logi.RTS+on+Raspberry+Pi) RT on pi. In this case, you can use PI like a PLC and logi.CAD3 like IDE where you can write ST program.
2. Use CoDeSys. ерун [have PI runtime too](https://store.codesys.com/codesys-control-for-raspberry-pi-sl.html?___store=en&___from_store=default). But it cost money per license. Install it and Codesys will be IDE for PI.
3. Use [OpenPLC](https://www.openplcproject.com/) Runtime and IDE. This will allow you to upload ST file on your PLC (Raspberry Pi)

Comment: How do I connect the RPi directly to the openPLC server, so that I can run the structured text language files on the server. I used the browser to directly connect the RPi using the IP address and it doesn't seem to work that way either. Should I do something on the terminal before I connect it through the browser?

Comment: I think you have to follow this instruction https://www.openplcproject.com/getting-started-rpi. After you install it, open through a web browser and upload ST file there.